# Missing separate debuginfos

Tags: gdb, fedora

I'm trying to debug a code using GDB in a Fedora machine. It produces this message each time I run it.

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.3-1.fc20.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.3-1.fc20.x86_64
```

My questions:

1. Should these packages be in GDB by default?
2. What is the function of each of these packages?
3. In real production environments should these packages be installed for GDB?
4. Is it ok if I do not install these packages? What will be the effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No. `gdb` is packaged by a maintainer, `glibc` is packaged by another maintainer, `gcc`, `libstdc` and so on all all packaged by different maintainers.  To package the debuginfo for these along with `gdb` would take considerable coordination.  Each time one of the packages changed, the `gdb` maintainer would have to repackage and release. It would become quite cumbersome to manage. `gdb` can also debug other languages, for example `java`, which wouldn't need the debuginfo for the libraries listed.
2. The `debuginfo` packages contain the source code and symbols stripped from the executable.  They are only required during debugging, therefore are redundant during normal use.  They do take up a fair amount of space, therefore are stripped during production releases.
3. It depends.  Most C code will use `glibc` etc.  However, if you're debugging package X and don't need to delve into the internals of `glibc` you could manage without installing it. If you want to follow the code in `gdb` all the way to the low-level `glibc`, or if you think there's a bug in the library itself, then you'll need to install it.  On the other hand, some C code might be statically linked and should have everything needed within it's own debuginfo package, or an application could be written in another language.  Neither would need these installed.
4. Yes. The effect of not installing these packages is that you will not be able to debug effectively into the routines provided by them.  As in 3 above, it all depends on whether you need to debug at that level or not.

**Note:** You'll find that many applications have been optimised (with the `-O` flag in the compiler) and don't debug that well with debuginfo.  A workaround is to recompile without any optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might be helpful to those whom have this warning.

1. They are packaged into different packages in fedora. The command `dnf install debuginfo-install packagename` can solve this warning.

My os is fedora 29 workstation x86_64. Debuginfo packages can be find in [archive repo](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/debug/tree/),
for example [glibc-debuginfo-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/debug/tree/Packages/g/glibc-debuginfo-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm), [glibc-debuginfo-common-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/debug/tree/Packages/g/glibc-debuginfo-common-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm), [libgcc-debuginfo-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/debug/tree/Packages/l/libgcc-debuginfo-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm), [libstdc++-debuginfo-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/debug/tree/Packages/l/libstdc++-debuginfo-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm).

Package for other editions just checks here, the [archive editions](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/) or the [latest editions](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/).

source code: [gcc-mirror online on github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/), [glibc online on sourceware](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git), [libstdc++ in gcc online source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00926_source.html).
The source packages including gcc, gdb, glibc on https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/

2. See [Why gdb is showing message "Missing separate debuginfos"?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1506273)

> To debug any application need it source code and debugging symbols installed on the system to get more information with respect to individual frames in the [stack](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/StackTraces).
>
> So debuginfo packages of all the dependencies of the binary trying to debug need to be installed.

The debuginfo packages including `.debug` files and source files. After installed those packages, `.debug` files will be stored in `/usr/lib/debug/lib64/` and source files in `/usr/src/debug/` for fedora 29. And a link `.gnu_debuglink` section will be added to glibc library file.

For example, `/usr/lib/debug/lib64/libc-2.28.so.debug` is installed from `glibc-debuginfo-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64`.

```bsh
[user@localhost myctest]$ rpm --query --list glibc-debuginfo-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64 | grep libc-2.28.so.debug
/usr/lib/debug/lib64/libc-2.28.so.debug
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf -S /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so | grep debug
  [73] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  002a6df0
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf -S /lib64/libc-2.28.so | grep debug
  [73] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  002a6df0
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf --debug-dump=links /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so 
Contents of the .gnu_debuglink section:

  Separate debug info file: libc-2.28.so.debug
  CRC value: 0x9bd5ece3
```

and source files:

```bsh
[user@localhost myctest]$ ls -l /usr/src/debug/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 60 root root 4096 Aug 10 18:36 glibc-2.28-110-g57922433fa
```

[The script that generates those packages is /usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Debuginfo/).

You can make your own `.debug` file manually.

Try an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    int n; 
    for (n=0; n<10; n++) { 
       printf("Print Number: %d\n", n); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

compile as debug edition executable file

```bsh
gcc example.c -o example.bin -g
```

create `.debug` file and remove debug section from `example.bin` file.

```bsh
objcopy --only-keep-debug example.bin example.debug
strip -g example.bin
```

Connect them together. Add `.gnu_debuglink` to `example.bin`.

```bsh
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=example.bin.debug example.bin
```

Then you have:

```bsh
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf --debug-dump example.bin 
Contents of the .gnu_debuglink section:

  Separate debug info file: example.bin.debug
  CRC value: 0xefae614e
```

3. In my fedora workstation x86_64 release edition, these debug packages are not installed by default. I don't think the debug files should be installed in the production environment.
4. It is for [StackTraces](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/StackTraces).

stack trace should look like:

```bsh
Reading symbols from example.bin...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401135: file example.c, line 6.
Starting program: /home/codc/works/cpp/example.bin 
warning: Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd5d8) at example.c:6
6       for (n=0; n<10; n++) {
(gdb) break printf
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7e32100: file printf.c, line 28.
(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>backtrace
>continue
>end
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __printf (format=0x402010 "Print Number: %d\n") at printf.c:28
28  {
#0  __printf (format=0x402010 "Print Number: %d\n") at printf.c:28
#1  0x0000000000401152 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd5d8) at example.c:7
Print Number: 0

Breakpoint 2, __printf (format=0x402010 "Print Number: %d\n") at printf.c:28
28  {
#0  __printf (format=0x402010 "Print Number: %d\n") at printf.c:28
#1  0x0000000000401152 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd5d8) at example.c:7
Print Number: 1
```